# Make Submit button go to URL from form element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to find a way to create a form with 2 fields. Username and Password. When the user clicks on submit it should take the username and password and add it to the URL in a specific place. 
For example:
http://www.mydomain.com/cgi-bin/USERNAME=username_entered_in_form&PWD=password_entered_in_form

The URL will remain the same except for:
"username_entered_in_form" should be replaced with the username and same with passowrd.

Then I would like for it to forward to another page.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Show what you have attempted so far

Comment: You should not be displaying a password in the URL bar in any circumstance. That is why `post` is a better option for what I presume is a sign in form

Comment: It's better to discourage the OP from doing what he wants rather than supplying him answers on a very unsafe act, no insult intended.

Answer (score 1):

create a form with GET method:

```
<form method="GET" action="login.php">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="pwd" />
</form>
```

Greetz

Hint:

Try to avoid sending sensible data via GET. For that reasons, better use the POST method:

```
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="pwd" />
</form>
```

Using PHP as in my example, you retrieve the data with either:

```
$_POST['username'] and $_POST['pwd']
or
$_GET['username'] and $_GET['pwd']
```

for GET method

Comment: +1 - Also make sure that you form elements have `name="USERNAME"` and 
`name="PWD"` also...

Comment: You should let the OP know about the implication of using a `GET` method in a `form` that has a password field.

Comment: @Trickzter Advising to send Password via get is not Good

Comment: @LifeHacker You are absolutely right, but the OP asked for a method to set the username and the pwd into the url, so I just answered it. But important to mention!

Comment: @Trickzter I like the PHP Post idea, but where do I specify the actual domain it should go to on the PHP page?

Comment: @Moe as you can see in my example, I defined the form-attribute "action". That's the path to your PHP file which interacts with your form. Means if you got your index.html in one folder and your login.php in the same folder, you simply write: action="login.php".

If you have your php files in a subdirectory called like "phps" you would need to define: action="phps/login.php".

Alright?

Comment: @Trickzter Thanks I see what you're saying so now I am able to do it, but the following page is blank. I still never defined the domain name for the link in the PHP file. Meaning, I want the username and password to get added to a specific web address not the same as the domain that's hosting the index.html and login.php file.

Comment: I am not quiet sure if I understand you correctly, but why don't you just build up a query string then?

For example:

the domain you wanna reach is: "www.iamadomain.com/login.php".
Then you save the username and pw with your login.php and use the php command: "header("Location: www.iamadomain.com/login.php?username=".$username."&pw=".$pw);

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Trickzter thanks so much for all your input, I clearly don't know enough to try something like this... so I'm messing around with it and trying to different things trial and error, i appreciate your help and have progressed a lot with your help.

Comment: That's what I wanna hear! You are welcome, just exam some php tutorials and you will learn it, we all started from the beginning!

Greetz

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="ttp://www.mydomain.com/cgi-bin/" method="get">
<input name="USERNAME" value="" placeholder="Username" type="text">
<input name="PWD" value="" placeholder="Password" type="password">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: Thx. Now it's work correctly. I thought that default method is GET.